# What's the easiest daily way to farm Common Data Crystals at level 51+?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I recently finished Act 3 on my newest character and hit level 51, and I was thinking it would help to deck me and my companion out with mods from the Makeb comms vendor. I had enough comms to take care of most of my slots, but not enough to even start on my companion.

How can I quickly acquire Common Data Crystals now? Techniques that are only doable once per day are fine as long as they're efficient.

Comment: Unless low level enemies don't drop loot for high levels, you could easily run through lower leveled areas and stomp on the enemies. You might come across some (but it is not the best way).

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much all low-level heroics give Common Data Crystals.

Here is a list with all Heroics, one for [Republic](http://dulfy.net/2012/05/13/heroic-quests-bonus-series-and-their-rewardsrepublic/) and one for the [Imperial](http://dulfy.net/2012/05/13/heroic-quests-bonus-series-and-their-rewardsempire/) side.
The rewards are outdated, the quests aren't.

If you're a Trooper or Smuggler you can get 9 Common Data Crystals by doing the heroics on Ord Mantell.

- [Weekly] Searching for Allies: Complete a random Flashpoint with the Group Finder. 10 Common Data Crystals.
- [Weekly] Priority Targets: Kill 3 world bosses. 30 Common Data Crystals

Comment: In 4.0 there are terminals on Odessen and the Fleet which list all Heroics available, plus rewards are granted instantly when completed (no turn-in) and you get quick travel items to go to the area of the quest.  That makes this far and away the most attractive option.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that they removed Planetary Commendations and replaced them with Basic Commendations (now renamed Common Data Crystals), you can do a variety of things to get them.

- Warzones reward you with Warzone Commendations, which can be exchanged for Common Data Crystals at one of the Warzone prize vendors. The daily and weekly Warzone quests give more Warzone Commendations that you can trade.
- Flashpoints (either normal or tactical) both give Common Data Crystals, either from bosses or completion, and the daily quests give even more, along with the weeklies.
- Heroics reward you with some.

(I will update this list as I locate more ways to obtain them.)